# flexbox stretching inside container

Tags: css, flexbox, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm trying to align 2 `figure` inside container.

Here is jade/pug layout.

```
.container-fluid
    section#feeds_container
            section.row
                section.col-sm-12.d-flex
                        figure#pagination_up.d-flex.justify-content-center
                        figure#button_wrapper.d-flex.justify-content-end
```

Tried `align-self-center` and `end` but unable to position the two elements, one in center at max width and other at right.

Please help.

Comment: Please post your CSS and the compiled HTML code.

Answer (score 2):

The `justify-content` property is supposed to be set to the parent element to which the `display: flex` is applied, which is `section.col-sm-12` in this case.

However, you don't need to set it to achieve your desired output and instead, add the class `mx-auto` to the first `<figure>` element.

```
.container-fluid
    section#feeds_container
            section.row
                section.col-sm-12.d-flex
                        figure#pagination_up.mx-auto First figure here
                        figure#button_wrapper Second figure here
```

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/vRgPYa)

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is that mx auto use center space of all space in between second figure and left side, the point is that pagination figure (first) to be centered exactly at col-sm-12 parent.

Comment: The almost my idea, is to make navigation pagination buttons at center, some button at right part, and to make it looks on mobile devices in single column not a row.

Comment: I think you already fixed it in your codepen. You have any more questions on it?

Comment: See this codepen too - https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/RMKXPw A different approach.

Comment: Yep, you can check it right now, I made fix by alot of experimenting, didn't code looks kinda overloaded?

Comment: Last problem here is that when on mobile device all fits in one column (block under block) seems they both goes slightly right side. Is there I should use that (position_absolute) snippet from yours second approach? or maybe there a easier way